# SSD gone after power outage

Tags: ssd

After a power outage my SSD dseems to be dead, it would be nice if i could get it to work again (obviously duh).

When i have it and start the PC it shows the BIOS screen but i cant get into the menu, after a few minutes it switches to a black screen with a single _ in the top left corner. Booting without the SSD connected gives a please select booting device or connect one and restart. Booting from a USB-stick works fine.

I tried leaving it on power for a while and disconnecting and reconnecting it without any luck.

[dmesg with the SSD connected](https://pastebin.com/bSsYwmWy)

[dmesg without SSD](https://pastebin.com/qUYvx7iA)

I'm only interested in a way that's saves the data or something easy that takes less then the 20 minutes I need to get to the store.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to get output (from Linux) if the SSD is dead, is the output from Linux on a usb or are you running linux off of another drive? If neither then the SSD is working. Also edit post if you do or do not care if you lose data on the SSD.

Comment: @el8tedN8te The output is from a Linux on usb. I'd prefer if I can keep the data but if it revives the drive I can live with losing it

Comment: Actually scratch that, the data loss option is going to the store I bought it at and demanding a new one since its only 2 months old

Answer (score 0):

The flashing underscore indicates that its trying to load an operating system or boot manager that is not indicated or leads to a non-existent boot file: this is likely due to a bad boot manager that it is not booting into, there is a corrupt operating system / grub bootloader (Grub is a 'OS' per say so it may have issues), or the SSD itself is having issues therefore preventing the loading.

I would consult these posts to try and re-emplace grub2 first, especially if you are able to navigate the partitions of the SSD with your Linux USB:

1. [From the AskUbuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126541/how-to-manually-install-boot-loader)
2. [From the AskUbutnu SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209919/how-to-use-grub-as-default-bootloader-while-dual-booting-win7ubuntu#)
3. [From HowToUbuntu.org](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

Otherwise you can reinstall Linux-first (with the OS of your choosing).

If for some reason that fails use [UBCD or Ultimate Boot CD.](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html) Navigate to Parted Magic from it boot screen. Select "Erase Disk". Now I would do multiple formations using different algorithms on the disk (I had a problem before with an SSD, and had to do multiple for it to work correctly). After that try installing the Linux Flavor of your choice.

If you want to try and scrap up some data and save it, I would use the multiple tools found on UBCD, especially test-disk. If you are having issues saving your UBCD, try some tests (that are compatible with your SSD brand (Seagate tools sometimes works on other brands) found within the menus) to tell the state of your drive and also more formatting tools (but the formatting methods before should have done the trick). After that try installing the Linux Flavor of your choice.

**BE CAREFUL:** If you want to save any data, you may mess up your SSD partitions by messing around with the tools in UBCD. I am not liable for what YOU CHOOSE to do! Consult the web if you are confused (but still be wary!)